# What resources would you recommend for learning about OS security?

Tags: windows, linux, security, operating-system

I'm interested to discuss security and want to work in this field.
I need a difference of useful resources!
I first want to study the security of operating systems,
both Windows and a version of Linux.

- Which Linux version is better for security work, and what is the best resource for learning?
- What is the best resource for learning Windows Security?
- What are the resources for learning programming under these operating systems?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/201857/networking-security-and-tcp-ip-internals-books-sites

Comment: There are already several similar questions on our IT Security site.  [Resources to learn about security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266/resources-to-learn-about-security), [Two questions about learning Linux exploit development fundamentals](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/two-questions-about-learning-linux-exploit-development-fundamentals), and [What security resources should a white-hat *developer* follow these days?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/571/what-security-resources-should-a-white-hat-developer-follow-these-days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not mean to be rude, but Google will really fetch you some updated articles on what you want. Trust me, I've been there. Also try YouTube.

There's no Linux "version". What you want is a distribution, or a distro! Try BackTrack Linux. It is hot among the sec guys, as it comes pre-loaded with all the security auditing tools you may need.

Get the book called "The Art of Exploitation" and get your hands dirty, even if that means running a deliberately vulnerable  Linux kernel (old, unpatched). That'll get you to learn the concepts of overflows, format-string attacks, injections etc.

The book mentioned discusses about Windows security(?) as well.

As far as programming is concerned, learn C/C++ first. Understand the low level UNIX system calls. Then, move on to learning WIN API (go to msdn and search) for Windows and strengthen your programming skills on Linux using a library related to what you like : study OpenGL/GLUT if you're into graphics, learn QT if you wish to build X-platform GUIs.
and, GET YOUR DATA STRUCTURES RIGHT.

"Programming" is an art that no one, nor any "resource" can teach you. You have to survive those segfaults, hair-pulling moments and evening-to-early-morning code marathons to actually bring out the "programmer" in you :)

EDIT: subscribe to security mailing lists :)

Happy (never-ending) journey, 
keep learning,

regards,

Yati

Comment: thanks Yati for useful guidance!